# Phaser3 ascii graphics

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework, game-development

Does anyone know how can I use text as sprites in phaser3?
I could create a sprite with an ascii spritesheet but because I want the text (in my case the sprites) to change colour, that solution wouldn't be optimal.

In phaser2 I could create an empty bitmapdata object and use it as the graphic for my sprite, but in phaser3 there is no such a thing.

Should I create a sprite with a transparent png as the graphic and then add the text to it? Is this a good solution or would it be an overkill, as in my game I want everything to be ascii characters?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your original solution of using a Sprite with an ASCII spritesheet will work fine. You can have white lettering and use the **setTint()**, **clearTint()**, and **isTinted** property to change the color while also being able to Sprite-related stuff.

1. [Tinting Demo](http://labs.phaser.io/view.html?src=src%5Cinput%5Cmouse%5Ctop%20only%20over%20and%20out%20events.js)
2. [Source Code](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-examples/blob/master/public/src/input/mouse/top%20only%20over%20and%20out%20events.js)
3. [Phaser 3 Sprite Doc](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html)